# Passing parameter to singleton

Tags: c#

I wrote this factory class in order to pass parameter to Singlton class, is it a good design in term of design for multithreading environment?

```
public static class LoggingServiceFactory
{
    private static string _connectionstring;
    private static readonly Lazy<LoggingService> _INSTANCE = new Lazy<LoggingService>(() => new LoggingService(_connectionstring));

    public static ILoggingService GetService(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionstring = connectionString;
        return _INSTANCE.Value;
    }

    private class LoggingService : ILoggingService
    {
        private string _connectionstring;
        internal LoggingService(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionstring = connectionString;
        }

        public void LogMessage(string msg)
        {
            // do the logging work
        }

    }
}

public interface ILoggingService
{
    void LogMessage(string msg);
}
```

Comment: Think if caller passes TWO different connection strings. Second time she will get an instance built using first c.s. and it's absolutely unexpected...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, OK, in this case, should it throw an exception? or to use a dependency injection and register the instance with parameter before anycode can see it.

Comment: DI unless connection string is somehow calculated at run-time. In that case you have to keep it as parameter but you may provide a Func<string> to retrieve connection when required.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti if DI is not available, how can you ensure users don't provide different Func<string> for the parameter? can you please provide an example?

Comment: They can provide multiple functions, of course, but you won't call them because instance has been already created. Of course in debug build you may always call it to check it didn't change.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti so what is the difference between if (
_connectionString != null)
                _connectionstring = connectionString;  and if (!_INSTANCE.IsValueCreated()) _connectionstring = func() The second connection string is still ignored silently.

Comment: Just to prevent calculation (as I said if it's fixed then it shouldn't be a parameter). But you are right about risk to ignore it, that's why in debug build it should be checked. Even better if you have such requirement then maybe singleton isn't perfect choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If connection string matching is a really necessary thing:

```
static class LoggingServiceFactory
{
    static readonly TaskCompletionSource<string> _cs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    static ILoggingService _service;

    public static ILoggingService GetService(string connectionString)
    {
        if (_cs.TrySetResult(connectionString))
            _service = new LoggingService(connectionString);
        else
            if (_cs.Task.Result != connectionString)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string redefinition.");

        return _service;
    }
}
```

Comment: you used TaskCompletionSource to set the connectionstring, is it for thread safty purpose?

Comment: Yep, exactly. It is a tread safe atomic operation. Succeeds one time only.

Comment: Cool, it is a better way than using locks for such simple senario.

Answer (score 2):

I would not personally put LoggingService implementation inside factory, as it reduces testability and usually needed to play some tricks with generics type parameters only.

To have a predictable behavior according to your design it might look like:

```
public static class LoggingServiceFactory
{
    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ILoggingService> Services { get; } = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ILoggingService>();

    public static ILoggingService GetService(string connectionString) =>
        Services.GetOrAdd(connectionString, cs => new LoggingService(cs));
}
```

Anyway, it makes sense to think about delegating it to IoC container...

I don't think that it is a responsibility of this class to verify if connection string is the same. This interface delivers different perception.